# Systemd invocation parameters

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd

This is a request for official documentation. As I understand it, kernel command line parameters, e.g.:

```
root=/dev/sda1 foo=bar
```

That are not recognized by the kernel itself are passed on to [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), on linux now most commonly **systemd**.

While the kernel's own parameters are [largely documented](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), I can't find any for systemd itself. `man systemd` does refer to a handful of things but it does not seem to cover this, and searching online has led me nowhere.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bigon notes, the official documentation you are looking for is in [`man kernel-command-line`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html).

Comment: I thought there was more it but I think this is as good as it is likely to get!